# How can I retreive all ingredient info from a recipe

Tags: mysql, sql

I'mtrying to retreive all of my ingredient info (id of the ingredient, type of ingredient, measure name, amount, name of the ingredient).

Here is how my database looks like :

[image]

**recipes**

```
------------------------
| id | name    | user_id
------------------------
| 1  | Lasagna | 1
```

**recipeingredient**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| recipe_id | ingredient_id | measure_id | amount
--------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 1             | 5          | 4
| 1         | 2             | 5          | 1
| 1         | 3             | 1          | 600
```

**ingredient**

```
-----------------------------
| id | name        | type_id
-----------------------------
| 1  | carrot      | 2
| 2  | onion       | 2
| 3  | ground beef | 3
```

**ingredient_type**

```
-----------------
| id | type
-----------------
| 1  | Fruit
| 2  | vegetable
| 3  | meat
```

**ingredient_measurment**

```
-----------------
| id | name
-----------------
| 1  | Gram
| 2  | Kgram
| 3  | grip
| 4  | pinche
| 5  |
```

I'm able to retreive the ingredient list using the following SQL :

```
SELECT name FROM ingredient WHERE id IN (SELECT ingredient_id from recipeingredient WHERE recipe_id = 1)
```

Output:

```
-----------------
| name
-----------------
| carrot 
| onion
| ground beef
```

But I would like to return some more info as described before. I would be happy to share the database on a third party to make some test request but I don't know any website.

Expected select data :

```
ingredient.name
ingredient_type.type
ingredient_measurment.name
recipeingredient.amount
```

Expected output :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| name        | ingredient_type | ingredient_measurment | amount |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| carrot      | vegetable       |                       | 4
| onion       | vegetable       |                       | 1
| ground beef | meat            | Gram                  | 600
```

Fidle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b91bd6/1

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT ing.name, ing_t.type, ing_m.name, r_ing.amount
  FROM ingredient ing
    JOIN ingredient_type ing_t on ing_t.id = ing.type_id
    JOIN recipeingredient r_ing ON ing.id = r_ing.ingredient_id
    JOIN ingredient_measurement ing_m ON ing_m.id = r_ing.measure_id
  WHERE r_ing.recipe_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, I have not had an editor to check syntax but this should be close.

```
 Select 
            r.name as Recipe,-- repeated for all ingredients and measurements.
            ing.name as Ingredient,
            ingt.type as IngredientTpe,
            ri.Amount as Amount,
            m.name as Measurement
FROM
            recipes r
LEFT JOIN   recipeingredient ri on ri.recipe_id  = r.id
LEFT JOIN   ingredient ing on ing.id = ri.ingredient_id 
LEFT JOIN   ingredient_type ingt on ingt.id = ing.type_id
LEFT JOIN   ingredient_measurment m int on m.id = ri.measure_id 
ORDER BY 
            1,4 DESC,5
```